# Change size fixed element with dynamic content?

Tags: html, position, fixed

Always i try to not ask about my problems, google about it etc. But now i have big problem with my code. I have http://html.bpcoders.pl/4hero/ left sidebar always visible, there is fixed position but content is bigger than height of sidebar and part of content is outside screen.
I dont have any ideas how i can do it for good utility. Did You have ANY ideas about it? Sorry for my englisj is not my first language .

Answer (score 0):

Add a scroll to your side bar by doing the following:

on you  element, add the css overflow-y : scroll;

so your element head would look as follows:

```
<aside style="overflow-y : scroll">
```